# i want to count the number of sentiments that are in excel which i have called with jspreadsheet, but it comes out #ERROR

Tags: javascript, excel, laravel, spreadsheet

```js
var name = document.getElementById("name").value;
var url = window.location.origin + '/storage/excel-data/' + name

jspreadsheet(document.getElementById('spreadsheet'), {
    worksheets: [{
        csv: url,
        search: true,
        csvHeaders: true,
        tableOverflow:true,
        tableHeight:'450px',
        columns: [
            { width:300 },
            { width:80 },
            { width:100 },
        ],
        footers:[
            [
                'Total Positif',
                '=COUNTIF(H:H,"positive")',
            ],
            [
                'Total Negatif',
                '=COUNTIF(H:H,"negative")',
            ]
        ],
    }]
});
```

[image: spreadsheet data]

Answer (score 0):

You need to use an extension JSpreadsheet Formula Pro to run this syntax.